# Choosing Bounds of Integration for a Triangle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

Suppose I have a region of integration boded by $x+y \le 8$ and $0 \le y \le x$. I have graphed the bounds, and they form a right triangle with its hypotenuse following the $x$-axis from $[0,8]$ and the right angle at $(4,4)$.

For clarity, the region I am looking at is the intersection of the red and green regions.

[image]

I am having trouble figuring out what the bounds should be. I was thinking of splitting up the double integral into two double integrals.

$\int^4_{0} \int^{y=x}_{y=0} f(x) dy dx + \int^8_{4} \int^{y=8-x}_{y=0} f(x) dy dx$

Is this correct?

Comment: Might help to look at the upper bound on $y$ in the second integral again! :)

Comment: It seems correct... but see the comment from @Khallil

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak ahh... sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost correct. For the second integral we still have the condition that $y\leq 8-x$. So the integral is

$$\int^4_{0} \int^{x}_{0} f(x) \, dy \, dx + \int^8_{4} \int^{8-x}_{0} f(x) \, dy \, dx$$

The  line $8-x$ is bounded by $4\leq x\leq 8$ ($\color{green}{\textrm{green line}}$). So we get the right half of the triangle area.

[image]